# Internet Explorer Hangs After Killing Process

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have Windows 7 OS and Internet Explorer 11 release.
Sometimes my IE crashes and due to that, I have the kill the process using Task Manager. When I re-start IE after killing the process, IE hangs, restore all pages is not able to click and my only option available is to re-start my PC.

My question, is there any setting available in IE which would help to get rid of this problem?

Appreciate any insight or help.

Comment: IE11 is a big security hole.

Comment: @harrymc Why I have asked this question is a couple of months back when I had this same issue, I did a google search and found a useful site which mentioned about a setting which would stop hanging the IE after killing the process. Unfortunately, I do not have the information available, neither I able to search google to find any useful information.

Comment: Was it one of [these](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/internet-explorer-freezes-crashes-hangs)?

Comment: @harrymc Well I will try any of those tomorrow, but I am not sure. Thanks

Comment: @harrymc My apologies for the late reply. Unfortunately, those are not the ones I was looking for. Thanks anyway.